# Cassandra incremental backups not working

Tags: cassandra

I have set incremental backup option to true in Cassandra.yaml and restarted the service. However I do not see "backups" directory created whenever I flush the memtable

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where are you looking for the backups directory?

Comment: /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace>/<sstable>-<uuid>/backups